# Regex: How to parse my custom syntax "a -> b : 1 | c : 2 : 3 | d e | f : 2"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making my own syntax for a piece of software in JavaScript that I'm designing.

Basically the user can input a string as:

`marking -> crossing : 1 | jumping : 2 : 3 | complete forward | dive : 2`

Where `marking` is the main key, `crossing`, `jumping`, `complete forward` and `dive` are actions and `1`, `2` and `3` are parameters for the actions.

The string has to conform to that syntax, therefore things like:

`marking -> crossing : 1 |`

or

`marking -> crossing :`

or

`marking -> crossing : |`

or

`-> crossing`

Have to be considered invalid.

I'm doing the job of parsing this syntax by:

1. Testing it against the following regex `/^[^->]+ *-> *[^|:]+( *: *[^|: ]+)*( *\| *[^|: ][^|:]+( *: *[^|: ]+)*)* *$/`
2. Splitting by `->`, then by `|` and lastly by `:`

And it works, but it's ugly.

Two questions:

1. Is there are a way to do it in one line by using `match()`?
2. Is there a better regex than the one I've come up with to test the validity of the syntax?

Comment: see a long article (TL;DR) about [Parsing expression grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), and to add to your first question: "Should it be done using a (or 1?) regular expression?"

Comment: Perhaps you could take this as an opportunity to learn how to write a proper parser. [Allen Holub has made his classic book on compiler design available as a PDF](https://holub.com/compiler/) - you might find it useful.

Comment: You mention "by using match()" which implies you have a particular programming language / library in mind, but you don't mention one in the question or tags.

Comment: Right, sorry I'm editing